# Affect of using a pattern generator with a laser?

Tags: optics, photonics

I've been thinking about laser pattern generators and the implications of using them. If we consider a normal laser diode with a Gaussian beam, then we can imagine a dot being projected onto a target. If we then consider a laser diode with a Gaussian beam then being equipped with a pattern generator – say, a line generator – then we can imagine a line being projected onto a target. But how does equipping the laser diode with the Gaussian beam with the line generator affect the properties of the beam that is then being projected onto the target? For instance, naively, one could hypothesise that, since the laser is no longer being concentrated as a dot, and is now spread over a much larger area (a line), that the beam is weaker in some way; perhaps the beam has decreased output power, or the beam, which is now a line, is no longer Gaussian. If this were not the case, then one could possibly see it as a 'free lunch' in the physics sense: the properties of the laser are the same, but now over a larger area (than just the dot), all simply because we changed the shape of the output beam by using a line generator.

I would also very much appreciate any references/research on this subject that I can use to learn about this.

Comment: The "true" amount of reflected light from a given area depends on the amount of time the beam hits that area (integrate the gaussian pattern as in moves, if you like).  But as the answer points out, our eyeball/brain system does a **lot** of integration and adjustment before "telling" us how bright something is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the "line" is much less bright than the "dot". No free lunch, just like everywhere else. The nature of things is safe again.

The power of the laser is spread over larger area and some is lost in the pattern generator as well.

Why we don't perceive the line much less bright:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stevens%27s_power_law

Human vision compresses the dynamic range of the picture. The laser-projected line is still much, much brighter than the surrounding area and eyes perceive light / no light. You don't have a reference light source to compare to.

And if you arrange the surrounding area to be not much less bright than the line, or you arrange the same dot together with the line, the line will look visibly less bright than the dot.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you have any good references to learn more about the things you described (decreased power, etc.)?

Comment: Well, hard to say. Energy conservation is everywhere.

Comment: I mean literature specific to photonics and pattern generators.